# How to prove if i a specified file on the webpage / webserver?

Tags: publishing

I have to prove if a specified file what i uploaded, was published in my site between two date. (so if i upload a file to my server, and publishing it today, and two days later somebody ask me to prove it, then i have to prove that file was published between 01.18.10-01.20.10)

Any solution interest which work.

I have no access to server logs.

Thank you for any suggestion...

Holian

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a digital signature of your file,
2. put it together with the file in a directory on the server,
3. list the contents of the directory,
4. and make a digital signature of this listing.

Comment: ohh...interesting..could you help me where can i start to learn something about this methode?